# g++ include all /usr/include recursively

Tags: c++, g++

I'm trying to compile a simple program, with

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
```

The path to `gtkmm.h` is `/usr/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm.h`. g++ doesn't see this file unless I specifically tell it `-I /usr/include/gtkmm-2.4`.

My question is, how can I have g++ automatically look recursively through all the directories in `/usr/include` for all the header files contained therein, and why is this not the default action?

Comment: I got it working (for `.cpp` files) automatically, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59621930/1599699

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In this case, the correct thing to do is to use `pkg-config` in your `Makefile` or buildscripts:

```
# Makefile
ifeq ($(shell pkg-config --modversion gtkmm-2.4),)
  $(error Package gtkmm-2.4 needed to compile)
endif

CXXFLAGS += `pkg-config --cflags gtkmm-2.4`
LDLIBS += `pkg-config --libs gtkmm-2.4`

BINS = program
program_OBJS = a.o b.o c.o

all: $(BINS)

program: $(program_OBJS)
        $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

# this part is actually optional, since it's covered by gmake's implicit rules
%.o: %.cc
        $(CXX) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

If you're missing `gtkmm-2.4`, this will produce

```
$ make
Package gtkmm-2.4 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtkmm-2.4.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtkmm-2.4' found
Makefile:3: *** Package gtkmm-2.4 needed to compile.  Stop.
```

Otherwise, you'll get all the appropriate paths and libraries sucked in for you, without specifying them all by hand.  (Check the output of `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-2.4`: that's far more than you want to type by hand, ever.)

Comment: I guess I just opened up a whole new headache for me to read about. Alright, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are not using a makefile? The only thing that could be annoying is having to type the long -I option *each time* you compile your program. A makefile makes it a lot easier.

For example, you could modify the *hello world* makefile from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) to something like the following:

```
INC=-I/usr/include/gtkmm-2.4/

helloworld: helloworld.o
    g++ -o $@ $<

helloworld.o: helloworld.c
    g++ $(INC) -c -o $@ $<

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f helloworld helloworld.o
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  The whole point of include paths is so you can pick and choose what you want and what versions.

What you could do is..

```
#include <gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm.h>
```

Which would achieve the same effect.

Comment: The problem with this is that gtkmm.h itself just includes a bunch of other headers with a path relative to its location that g++ cannot find .. :/. It is irritating.

I guess I could go through and replace all the paths in gtkmm.h, but I am hoping for another solution.

Comment: @endeavormac: what form do the relative includes take in gtkmm.h?  Basically, you are expected to specify the directory where gtkmm.h is found via -I and it will then, most likely, work correctly. Without that, it won't. Full stop - or period, if you prefer. Why do want to battle against the design?