# How to include header files in GCC search path?

Tags: c++, gcc, header

I have the following code in a sample file:

```
#include "SkCanvas.h"
#include "SkDevice.h"
#include "SkGLCanvas.h"
#include "SkGraphics.h"
#include "SkImageEncoder.h"
#include "SkPaint.h"
#include "SkPicture.h"
#include "SkStream.h"
#include "SkWindow.h"
```

However, this code is located in various folders within /home/me/development/skia (which includes core/ animator/ images/ ports/ svg/ and a lot more.)

How can I make GCC recognize this path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558803/how-to-add-a-default-include-path-for-gcc-in-linux

Comment: Very useful g++ build instructions for googletest/gtest: https://ethz-adrl.github.io/ct/ct_core/doc/html/md__home_adrl_code_src_control-toolbox_ct_core_build_test_googletest-src_googletest_README.html

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Try `gcc -c -I/home/me/development/skia sample.c`.

Comment: Glad to see this answer here. Another point worth mentioning would be that when you have many ".c" source files, it's necessary to specify each and every one of them in the commandline itself. You can't just do something like a -I to specify that all source files are in a certain directory.

Comment: If the header is in the same directory as the source, do you need a special include?  I can't get my code to compile either way, and I'm not sure what the problem is

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/510151/1403102) to a similar question, `gcc` would not search the subdirectories for the different header files automatically. Instead, `pkg-config` could produce the proper `-I` option?

Comment: What's the difference between `-I` and `-L`?

Comment: @falsePockets The `-L` flag tells GCC to include a library. For example, `gcc -c -c a.c` will include `libmath`. The `-I` flags tells GCC to include files from a different directory.

Comment: @EdwinPratt Perhaps you meant to say that `-L` tells GCC where to *look* for binary libraries to include (which are specified with `-l`). And `-I` tells GCC where to look for header files to include.

Answer (score 37):

The `-I` directive does the job:

```
gcc -Icore -Ianimator -Iimages -Ianother_dir -Iyet_another_dir my_file.c
```

Comment: To anyone needing this: it looks like you can include directories with spaces in them with quotes: `-I"some path/with spaces"`.

Answer (score 10):

Using environment variable is sometimes more convenient when you do not control the build scripts / process.

For C includes use `C_INCLUDE_PATH`.

For C++ includes use `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`.

See this [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html) for other gcc environment variables.

### Example usage in MacOS / Linux

```
# `pip install` will automatically run `gcc` using parameters
# specified in the `asyncpg` package (that I do not control)

C_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/scott/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/include/python3.7m pip install asyncpg
```

### Example usage in Windows

```
set C_INCLUDE_PATH="C:\Users\Scott\.pyenv\versions\3.7.9\include\python3.7m"

pip install asyncpg

# clear the environment variable so it doesn't affect other builds
set C_INCLUDE_PATH=
```