# gcc Can't Find a Included Header

Tags: c, gcc, header

I'm using a header called `colors.h` to organize my source code. The header is like this:

```
#define DEFAULT 0x07
#define BLACK 0
#define GRAY 7
#define BLUE 9
#define GREEN 10
#define CYAN 11
#define RED 12
#define MAGENTA 13
#define YELLOW 14
```

I'm putting the header at the same directory of the main source code, called `kernel.c`, and including it like this:

```
#include <colors.h>
```

But when I try to compile, I'm getting this:

> ubuntu@eeepc:~/Development/Test$ gcc -o kernel.o -c kernel.c -Wall -Wextra -nostdlib -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs
>   kernel.c:1:20: error: colors.h: No such file or directory
>   ubuntu@eeepc:~/Development/Test$

What I can do to solve this?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973146/how-to-include-header-files-in-gcc-search-path among many others.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use quotes:

```
#include "colors.h"
```

Using quotes will look in the same directory first, and then in the specified include paths.
Using angle brackets will look in the include paths only.

Answer (score 2):

Angle brackets are used to find a header in the implicit header paths. Headers in explicit paths, including the current directory, need quotes.

Answer (score 1):

`#include <colors.h>`  tells GCC to look where it finds the standard C headers, probably not where you have your header. `#include "colors.h` tells GCC to look for headers in the current working directory

Comment: So you want to use the latter in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "colors.h"
```