# Header files linked to from header file not found.

Tags: c, gcc, linker, header-files

I have a problem with Nvidia's OpenCl/Cuda framework, but I think it is a `gcc` linking issue.

The `opencl_hello_world.c` example file uses following header file:

```
#include "../OpenCL/common/inc/CL/opencl.h"
```

with `opencl.h` using these header files:

```
#include <../OpenCL/common/inc/CL/cl.h>
#include <../OpenCL/common/inc/CL/cl_gl.h>
#include <../OpenCL/common/inc/CL/cl_gl_ext.h>
#include <../OpenCL/common/inc/CL/cl_ext.h>
```

So all the header files are in the same folder.

When I then compile with `gcc opencl_hello_world.c -std=c99 -lOpenCL` I get following error messages:

```
error: ../OpenCL/common/inc/CL/cl.h: No such file or directory
error: ../OpenCL/common/inc/CL/cl_gl.h: No such file or directory
...
```

Even though `cl.h` and the other header files are located in this folder.

Having searched SO, I then changed the includes in the `opencl.h` to

```
   #include "cl.h"
   #include "cl_gl.h"
```

how I have read here: [gcc Can't Find a Included Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139920/gcc-cant-find-a-included-header).

But messing around with the frameworks header files does not seem like the way to go? What would be the proper way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're using both #include "" form and #include <>, which don't search in the same paths. "" is local to your project, and the -i command line specified to gcc, <> is the 'system' path specified by -I to gcc.

You probably need to set the include path with -Ipath/to/includes in gcc's command line.

Comment: so I add `-I../OpenCL/common/inc/CL/` but I still get the error:  `.../OpenCL/common/inc/CL/cl.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: Since the path is already in the #include <>, you should pass to -I the path BEFORE ../OpenCL/etc, not after.

Comment: Hi jv42, thank you for the tipp: I tried `gcc opencl_hello_world.c -I/home/myuseraccount/Documents/projects/opencl/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -lOpenCL`, but the error is still: `../OpenCL/common/inc/CL/cl.h: No such file or directory`. I think, I overlooked something stupid.

Comment: Are you sure about the include path? Don't forget it starts with ".." in the NV code...