# Gcc fails to recognize `-I../path`

Tags: gcc, linker, header-files

I have a problem with linking and gcc, probably resulting from a stupid mistake on my side. Drawing from this post [Header files linked to from header file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667184/header-files-linked-to-from-header-file-not-found), I tried the `-I` option to inlcude header files, but gcc just does not seem to recognize the parameter.

```
~/Documents/projects/opencl/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/src_l$ gcc opencl_hello_world.c –I../OpenCL/common/inc/CL/ –L/usr/local/cuda/lib –lOpenCL
gcc: –I../OpenCL/common/inc/CL/: No such file or directory
gcc: –L/usr/local/cuda/lib: No such file or directory
gcc: –lOpenCL: No such file or directory
In file included from opencl_hello_world.c:6:
../OpenCL/common/inc/CL/opencl.h:42:40: error: ../OpenCL/common/inc/CL/cl.h: No such file or directory
../OpenCL/common/inc/CL/opencl.h:43:43: error: ../OpenCL/common/inc/CL/cl_gl.h: No such file or directory
../OpenCL/common/inc/CL/opencl.h:44:47: error: ../OpenCL/common/inc/CL/cl_gl_ext.h: No such file or directory
../OpenCL/common/inc/CL/opencl.h:45:44: error: ../OpenCL/common/inc/CL/cl_ext.h: No such file or directory
```

When I input the command `cd ../OpenCL/common/inc/CL/` it brings me to the right folder with the right header files in it.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: I was about to ask the same exact question (OpenCL and all)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if `-` in `-I`, `-L`, `-l` is not in some other language.

It seems like some unicode symbol, not ascii.

That's why they are not recognized as `gcc` options but source files.

Comment: Thanks, I coppied the cmd from a web page and it was a indeed a different symbol.