# Problems with OpenCL

Tags: c, shell, opencl

I have a problem in compiling simple program using openCL under Ubuntu. I have downloaded the AMD stream SDK from the AMD site and I have installed it using the installation notes from the same site. I have copied a simple hello world program from a OpenCL manual and I've tried to compile it  using the command suggested from manual :

```
gcc -o hello -I '$AMDSTREAMSDKROOT/include' -L '$AMDSTREAMSDKROOT/lib/x86_64' hello.c ‐lOpenCL
```

but the answer from the compiler is

```
gcc: error: ‐lOpenCL: no such file or directory
```

Does anyone has any ideas about this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668680/gcc-fails-to-recognize-i-path

Comment: Yes.. But it doesn't work for me.. For now my solution is removing -L directive and substitute it with the whole path of the library.. But I don't know why the solution with the inclusion of a search path doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be using *strong quotes* (single quotes), which will prevent the environment variable `$AMDSTREAMSDKROOT` from being expanded. Try using double-quotes instead:

```
gcc -o hello -I "$AMDSTREAMSDKROOT/include" -L "$AMDSTREAMSDKROOT/lib/x86_64" hello.c ‐lOpenCL
```