# Source file cannot find the header files

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ubuntu-12.04, header-files

I have looked at these links : [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667184/header-files-linked-to-from-header-file-not-found?lq=1)
and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139920/gcc-cant-find-a-included-header?lq=1)
and a couple of other similar ones. 
 None of the answers given here are working methods are working.

I have a two source files `a1.c` , `a2.c` and two header files `a1.h` and `a2.h` . I want to include the header files in both these files (and a2.c in a1.c as there is a function I need to use from a2.c)

I have included

```
#include "a1.h"  
#include "a2.h"
```

in the source files of a1.c

I'm using GCC on Ubuntu. and using the command `gcc a1.h -o a1.out -lm`
and that didn't work.

I tried with

```
gcc -c -I/Home/Documents/ctests/ a1.c -o a1.out
```

as well as

```
gcc -c a1.c -I/Home/Documents/ctests/ -o a1.out
```

My spellings are okay as well (there's hardly any room for error there with one letter and a number as the filename anyway).

Also, all the files are in the same folder.

I know this may be a trivial question but I am stuck on this one and would appreciate any help. I am relatively new to programming and completely new to Linux and Unix as far as using the command line goes.

Many thanks!

Comment: If all files are in the same folder and you start GCC from this folder there is not need to use option `-I` to find `a1.h`and `a2.h`.

Comment: What error messages does GCC issue?

Comment: I get the same error all the time: No such file or directory

Comment: Did you `cd` to the folder where your `.h` and `.c` files reside?

Comment: *Why shouldn't I include .c files in other .c files?* The whole idea behind creating different modules is that you shouldn't have to recompile your *entire* project every time. If you only change `a2.c`, you should only have to recompile `a2.c` and link the old, unchanged `a1.o` (which shouldn't be recompiled because it *doesn't* include `a2.c`) with the new `a2.o`, like in stardust_'s answer.

Comment: @alk: yes I did cd to the same folder. I cd'd to that folder and created the files from there. So that's not the problem.
@modifiablelvalue: I didn't quite understand exactly what you were saying. I just intend to make one .out file at the end. I want to use functions stored in `a2.c` in `a1.c` and variables and macros defined in `a1.h` to be used in these two functions.
But the compiler doesn't acknowledge the `a1.h` file at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
gcc -c
```

tells gcc to compile the file to object (the .o files you see everywhere). To be linked later with some other .o files to an executable.

So what you want to do is either compile the two files separately and link them later. like this.

```
gcc -I"/Home/Documents/ctests/" -c a1.c
gcc -I"/Home/Documents/ctests/" -c a2.c

gcc -o myprogram a1.o a2.o
```

Or just compile and link at the same time.

```
gcc -I"/Home/Documents/ctests/" a2.c a1.c -o myprogram
```

And then run your program like

```
path_to/myprogram
```

Comment: Don't you mean `gcc a1.o a2.o -o myprogram` ?

Comment: `gcc -o a1.o a2.o myprogram` is the same. isn't it?

Comment: No it isn't. It will try to compile/link `a2.o` and `myprogram` to create an executable `a1.o`. (At least my gcc 4.7.2 does)

Comment: Oh dear god. How did i do that. I have fixed it. Tanks.

Comment: I don't need to link them later. I just used the -c option as a force of habit. Even If I remove it, it gives me the same error. 
I just need those header files to be visible to the a1.c file. And that's the first step where it's showing me the error.

Comment: Are the headers in the same folder as .c files? or in the folder `/Home/Documents/ctests/`? Also put the exact error message gcc gives you. Add an edit to your question if you need space

Comment: btw `a2.c` probably needs to include the .h files too. It is not enough to include it just in `a1.c`

Comment: @stardust_ : Both are in the same folder. But I realized where I goofed up. Thanks for reminding me that a2.c needs the header files as well. 
I had written it as `#include<a1.h>` in the second source file. 

Silly mistake.

Comment: And I didn't need to use the -I directory option either

Comment: Yes. for this example you don't need -I option. I think you have figured out the differece between <> and "".

Answer (score 1):

Compile everything, and link it together.

If all files are in one directory, this should work:

```
  gcc a1.c a2.c -o myapp
```

When you want to create separate object files, do this:

```
  gcc -c a1.c a2.c
```

Then you can then link together to create an application:

```
  gcc a1.o a2.o -o myapp
```

Answer (score 0):

Your gcc command should be like this

```
gcc -I/Home/Documents/ctests/ -o a1.out a1.c
```

and you have to include `a1.h` and `a2.h` header file in your `a1.c` like this

```
#include "a1.h"
#include "a2.h"
```

If you are calling some function from `a2.c` in your `a1.c` then you have to build your program in this way

```
gcc -I/Home/Documents/ctests/ -o a1.out a2.c a1.c
```

Comment: Files are included this way and the above gcc code is the same as writing
    gcc -I/Home/Documents/ctests/ a1.c -o a1.out
if i'm not mistaken. And this doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @Ade did you use some function from a2.c in a1.c ? if it's the case I updated my answer with that case

Comment: Yes I did. And that was the problem. Many Thanks!