# GCC unable to find header file in a included library

Tags: c, gcc, libraries

I am trying to include a library file named *libmathematica.a* in gcc so it gets linked in the executable *example*.

I attempt to do this with `gcc main.c libmathematica.a -o example`

*Note: I have to do this with gcc, as ld won't link it properly with the correct system libraries*

But I get: `fatal error: mathematica.h: No such file or directory` ,which is odd because *mathematica.h* is in the library.

Can you help?

Comment: See also: [c - gcc Can't Find a Included Header - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139920/gcc-cant-find-a-included-header)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A header file cannot be *in the library*. It has to be present at a certain location and you have to specify that location with the `-I` compiler flag:

```
gcc -I/path/to/mathematica/include main.c libmathematica.a -o example
```

If the header file is in the directory where the `main.c` is or in a subdirectory, then be sure that you use quotes and not angle brackets in the `#include` directive.

Answer (score 5):

The issue would be in your source file. If the mathematica.h is in the system includes directory then you would use `#include <mathematica.h>` and if it was in some local directory then you would use something like `#include "libs/mathematica.h"`.

Comment: I don't follow... See main.c isn't part of mathematica.a, its a external program. I'm trying to link mathematica to example to run code from mathematica

Comment: Where is the mathematica.h file located? do something like find / -name "*mathematica.h" . If it is in the main includes such as /usr/include then you can use #include <mathematica.h> otherwise it should be placed in the same directory as your main.c and use #include "mathematica.h".

Answer (score 1):

Try adding to the  gcc  call - an option like
   -I/Full/Path/To/The/Directory/Where/the/desired/header/resides

For example:
  gcc -I/usr/include/mathematica  -lmathematica -o example main.c