# Compiling a header file without the use of a makefile

Tags: c

As the title implies, I have a code file in C language and a Header file with its implemantation. What should I write in the command line on an oparating Linux-like system in order to make an executable programme?

Comment: You do not compile headers, and header files typically do not contain "a code file's implementation" as you say. This question makes very little sense.

Comment: The program you (probably) want is called `gcc`. Google will tell you more.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: The subject line of your question has no relationship to the body

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but even more importantly,
please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).
At least, you should specify the two file names — `codefile.c` and `header.h` would be better than nothing — and confirm that `codefile.c` contains a line `#include "header.h"`. Even without any makefile, typing `make codefile` would compile `codefile.c` to create an executable `codefile`; you could also type `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -o codefile codefile.c`. If it doesn't compile, you should include error messages in an edit of the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
gcc file.c -o yourProgram
./yourProgram
```

Answer (score -1):

A shell script running gcc on all the .c files you with to compile.

The bug advantage of make is that correctly written, it will only compile changed files saving you on build times especially during development

Answer (score -1):

First you need to look at what compilers (if any) are installed with your system (which gcc). Assuming you have gcc, look at this question which should provide an answer:

[How to compile a C program in gcc which has header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165548/how-to-compile-a-c-program-in-gcc-which-has-header-files)

note that gcc CodeFile.c -o ExecutableName is a basic command to compile a basic executable from the .c itself.

Or, make your #include statements use relative paths, depending on how your code base is structured.