# How can I compile a header file and a C file together?

Tags: c, header-files

I created a `file.h` and a `file.c` how can I compile them on Ubuntu?

Comment: Duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165548/how-to-compile-a-c-program-in-gcc-which-has-header-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compile a C program in gcc which has header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165548/how-to-compile-a-c-program-in-gcc-which-has-header-files)

Comment: You need a compiler. Download gcc?

Answer (score 3):

**You only need to compile your `.c` file(s), not your `.h` file(s).**

To compile `file.c` on Ubuntu, you can use [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/):

```
gcc file.c -o my_program
```

...or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/):

```
clang file.c -o my_program
```

It is possible to precompile your header files, but you only need precompiled headers in particular cases. [More information here.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html)

---

**If `file.h` is not in the same folder as `file.c`, you can use GCC or Clang's `-I` option.**

Example if `file.h` is in the `include/` folder:

```
gcc -I include/ file.c -o my_program
```

In `file.c` you still have this instruction, with only the filename:

```
#include "file.h"
```

Comment: I recommend `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g file.c -o file` or `clang -Wall -Wextra -g file.c -o myprog`, perhaps with `-I include/` since you need warnings and debug info (and  `gcc` or `clang` don't provide them by default)

Comment: And using `-Werror` too ensures that you don't try running code while it still has the compiler warning you — it converts all warnings into errors.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a more generic approach by the usage of a makefile.

Here is a short example of such a file:

```
# Declaration of variables
CC = gcc
CC_FLAGS = -w -Werror -Wall

# File names
# "prgoram" will be the name of the output produced from the make process
EXEC = program 
#Incorporates all the files with .c extension
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

# Main target
$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXEC)

# To obtain object files
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CC_FLAGS) $< -o $@

# To remove generated files
clean:
    rm -f $(EXEC) $(OBJECTS)
```

To use this utility just make sure that the file itself is within the directory containing your source files and its name is either "makefile" or "Makefile".
To compile the code simply run the following command from your working directory:

```
   make program
```

This command will automatically link all the source files within your working directory into one executable file with the name of "program". To run the program itself just use the command:

```
  ./program
```

To clean your project and the created executable you can run the command:

```
  make clean
```

The makefile is  very powerful when dealing with larger projects that contain a larger number of source files. [Here](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/) you can check for more guidance on how to use makefiles. [This is](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/1.19/makepp_tutorial.html) also a very detailed tutorial on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Use following command to compile your program(For GCC Compiler):

```
gcc file.c -o file
```

No need to compile file.h file.

Comment: It still doesn't compile it. It says "reference not defined to "main""

Comment: @user541409  I think you have two or more .c file.

Comment: No, it's just one.

Comment: @user541409 Make sure you have defined a function called `main()` inside your `.c` file. This is the first function that's called when you start your program, so you need to define one.

Comment: I recommend `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g file.c -o file` since you need warnings and debug info (and  `gcc` don't provide them by default)