# how to modify the path of a .h file when using #include <>?

Tags: c, gcc

when we use #include < stdio.h > in linux platform, the compiler will search the stdio.h in /usr/include. How to change the path of using #include<>?
thank you.

I asked the question because of this : when I use the C standard function isdigit(), if "#include< ctype.h >" is not added, the program generates a warning but no error. But if "#include < ctype.h >" is added,it will generate an error when linking.(My compiler is not the standard gcc.)

I wonder why?

Comment: For standard Libc headers I would avoid doing that. You need the `<stdio.h>` paired with your `libc.so`. You can have big trouble if you change it, unless you understand very well what you are doing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include header files in GCC search path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973146/how-to-include-header-files-in-gcc-search-path)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 -I dir
     Add the directory dir to the list of directories to be
     searched for header files.  Directories named by -I are
     searched before the standard system include directories.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different ways:

1. Use [`-Idir`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html#Search-Path) in the Makefile or as an argument to gcc.
2. Create environment variable [`C_INCLUDE_PATH`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Environment-Variables.html) (for C header files) or [`CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Environment-Variables.html) (for C++ header files).