# Box2D can't find it's eponymous head(er)

Tags: c++, box2d

I'm trying to compile the helloworld application that comes with Box2D. Unfortunately I'm not having a lot of luck...

At first I was having a compile error that went like so:

```
HelloWorld.cpp:19:25: fatal error: Box2D/Box2D.h: No such file or directory
```

The line in question is as so:

```
#include <Box2D/Box2D.h>
```

I went, oh, well it's in it's own directory called helloworld. It needs to be moved out into the sunshine (root directory of the engine), where a /Box2D/Box2D.h actually exists...

```
HelloWorld.cpp:19:25: fatal error: Box2D/Box2D.h: No such file or directory
```

Uh, maybe if I changed the line like so?

```
#include </Box2D/Box2D.h>
```

Let's try that.

```
HelloWorld.cpp:19:25: fatal error: /Box2D/Box2D.h: No such file or directory
```

Joy! The same error, with an extra character.

After about 15 minutes spent furiously googling, I figured out that I was discluding an -I from the compile path. It now looked like this:

```
g++ -Wall -c -I. "%f"
```

Try compile...Success! Now to move onto build, which shouldn't be a problem at -

```
HelloWorld.cpp:19:25: fatal error: Box2D/Box2D.h: No such file or directory
```

Suddenly a helloworld program doesn't seem simple at all.

I tried adding -I to my build path to no avail:

```
g++ -Wall -o "%e" "%f"
g++ -Wall -o -I. "%e" "%f"
```

Neither worked.

What am I to do, to conquer this vile HelloWorld application?

Comment: what about cmake? Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

You should not move the header around the directories. All you need is to add directory with header to the header search paths list. See this for example [How to include header files in GCC search path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973146/how-to-include-header-files-in-gcc-search-path)