# How to add includes when compiling DLL

Tags: c++, dll, compilation, include, 64-bit

I'm begginer in C/C++ and I have issue that i can't compile DLL(64bit).
I have headers and source codes (one is major and other are called) and when I try to compile I stuck on that I need to include stdint.h from c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\stdint.h and this header includes other and other... and I'm not able to set compilation in that way.

When I try using gcc:

```
gcc -c mdi_helper.c
In file included from mdi_helper.h:5:0,
                 from mdi_helper.c:18:
stdint.h:6:19: fatal error: yvals.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

And got the same result trying to compile it in VS2010.

Please can anyone help me with that? Never done something like this.

Comment: Can you show `mdi_helper.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide include paths for each directory containing header files that you need.

For gcc, use the `-I` command line parameter.

For VS, use the `/I` command line parameter.

Try this for VS2010:

```
cl mdi_helper.c /I"C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include"
```

Also for VS2010 you can set this in the IDE under *PROJECT->Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->General*, in the *Additional Include Directories*.

See this article with a similar question, [How to include header files in GCC search path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973146/how-to-include-header-files-in-gcc-search-path)