# Accessing header files in a large C++ project by <...>

Tags: c++, swig, distutils

I have a project with two packages:

Project

```
|-- Package_A
  |-- exA.cpp
  |-- exA.h
|-- Package_B
  |-- exB.cpp
  |-- exB.h
```

In this project say, `exB.cpp` references to `exA.h` as

```
#include <Package_A/exA.h>
```

However, I want to use `SWIG` to create a Python interface for this file using `distutil`s. I include following code in Extension definition:

```
sources=["Package_A/exA.cpp", "Package_B/exB.cpp"]
include_dirs=["Package_A/exA.h", "Package_B/exB.h"]
```

I have an error in compilation about header references. I can suspend that error if I use:

```
#include "../Package_A/exA.h"
```

There are many files like this. How I can I enable referencing with`<...>`?

Comment: The name `include_dirs` should probably be a hint about what you should put in it. Try e.g. `include_dirs=["."]` and see if you can figure out what difference that makes.

Comment: Sure, my mistake. I should put the directory there. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For compiler <...> means search for include in defined include paths.
Simply define include path when compiling. Similar problem already answered:
[How to include header files in GCC search path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973146/how-to-include-header-files-in-gcc-search-path)