# Is there a way to configure makefile to link extra objects on debug mode?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to write a makefile which supports release mode and debug mode, while in debug mode, I want to link an extra object `debug.o` to override functions for debugging.

For example:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -I$(INCPATH)

INCPATH = include
TARGET = foo
OBJ = foo.o bar.o

# release mode
all: build run clear

# debug mode
debug: CFLAGS += -g -DDEBUG
debug: OBJ += debug.o
debug: build gdb-run clear

# link objects
build: $(OBJ)
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJ)

# compile source code
%.o: %.c $(INCPATH)/*.h
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c $@ $<

# default run mode
run:
    ./$(TARGET)

# debug run mode
gdb-run:
    gdb --args $(TARGET)

clear:
    rm -f $(OBJ) $(TARGET)
```

I expected it expand `$(OBJ)` to `foo.o bar.o debug.o` when I call `make debug`, but instead it only expands to `foo.o bar.o`, because targets are expanded immediately when parsed.

I've tried using `.SECONDEXPANSION:`, but couldn't work it out.

And I've also tried `$(eval OBJ += debug.o)`, but that resulted in expanding `$(OBJ)` to `foo.o bar.o debug.o` even while running `make all`.

Is this possible, or should I just work around?

edit: fixed a typo, thanks to @matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the [GNU make "conditional" mechanism](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Example) with a *make* variable named MODE for this. In your case, what about

```
MODE = RELEASE
OBJ = foo.o bar.o
ifeq ($(MODE),DEBUG)
   OBJ += debug.o
endif
[...]
```

Then build with either

```
make    # a MODE=RELEASE build by default
```

or

```
make MODE=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

> I expected it expand $(OBJ) to foo.o bar.o debug.o

It does this inside the recipe, but not in the prerequisite list.

[6.11 Target-specific Variable Values](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html)

> As with automatic variables, these values are only available within the context of a target’s recipe (and in other target-specific assignments).

So you have to stick with conditionals to achieve your goal.

BTW. `CFLAGS = -Wall -I(INCPATH)` is a typo. `%.o: %.c $(INCPATH)/*.h` is plainly wrong - use $(wildcard ...) when really needed. Also change all occurences of `build` to `$(TARGET)`, as it's really `foo` what you're building. Then revise your makefile - it's probably not a good idea to clean everything after every run.

Comment: How is `CFLAGS = -Wall -I(INCPATH)` wrong? That is what I use exactly in my makefile, and it compiled with no complains. I also found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973146/how-to-include-header-files-in-gcc-search-path).       



I clean the binaries every time, because `make debug` won't recompile the objects with the `-DDEBUG` flag if there are left over binaries from `make all`, what is the better way of doing it?

Comment: @Tsiruan `How is CFLAGS = -Wall -I(INCPATH) wrong?` Must be `-I$(INCPATH)` obviously. `what is the better way of doing it?` Just `make -B` will do the full rebuild without any problems. However, it's better to put release and debug binaries into different directories.